# Безопасное выделение памяти для сокета

Tags: c, linux, сокет

Меня интересует, насколько опасна/безопасна такая работа с сокетом и буфером:

```
char message[] = "Hello there!\n";
char buf[sizeof(message)];
send(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0);
while(1) 
{
    recv(sock, buf, sizeof(message), 0);    
    printf(buf);//тут обработка принятого сообщения
}
```

если конкретно, то интересно, переполняем ли buf? Что вообще происходит с памятью, когда работает recv()?

Comment: Почему вы решили что буфер переполнится, мы же читаем в него не больше, чем он размером

Comment: @Александр Харук  Почему бы вам не почитать описание функции, прежде чем ее использовать?

Comment: Допустим, компилятор выделил под buf 15 байт. А теперь я принимаю сообщение в 50 байт, а оно успешно принимается. Все 50 байт выводятся. Вот это меня и смутило.

Comment: @АлександрХарук Покажите код, где было прочитано больше байтов, чем вы указали.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow код выше.
Что на входе: $ netcat -l -p 123123
Hello there!
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Что на выходе: $ netcat -l -p 123123
Hello there!
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

Comment: Принимается-то не больше, чем указано! Принимается sizeof

Comment: @АлександрХарук Извините, но я не понимаю, что вы пишите. Еще раз: почитайте описание функции.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, тут возможна проблема с `printf(buf);`.

Вы не записываете двоичный ноль (*nil*) после полученных по `recv()` данных. А `printf(buf)` будет просматривать `buf`, пока не встретит *nil*.

Более того, если в принятых данных будут элементы формата (т.е. `%s`, `%d` и т.п.), то `printf` полезет за несуществующими аргументами. Скорее всего дело закончится SIGSEGV (а вообще-то, такую ситуацию принято называть UB (undefined behavior)).

Правильно будет написать так:

```
char buf[sizeof(message)];
int l;

while ((l = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(message) - 1, 0)) > 0) {
   buf[l] = 0;
   printf("%s", buf);
   ...
}
// анализ l и errno обработка завершения
```

Comment: Спасибо, но printf(buf) исключительно для иллюстрации того, что после приёма идёт обработка. Ничего более.

Comment: @АлександрХарук, ОК, только *nil* в конце получаемых данных, если Вы их обрабатываете как текст, все равно не помешает.

Comment: Предотвратить поиск нулевого байта можно так: `printf("%.*s", sizeof buf, buf);`

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Ничего плохого с памятью не произойдёт. В буфер всегда будет приниматься не более sizeof(message). Это из-за цикла у меня создалось впечатление, что в буфер принимается слишком большое сообщение. Работа происходит только с char buf[sizeof(message)];
Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос. Спасибо за внимание.